# finally tagless parsing and recursive monadic actions

Tags: haskell, encoding, attoparsec

i deserialize a data structure from disc in the finally tagless style. i.e.

```
class SYM repl where
    a :: repl
    include :: FilePath -> repl 

myParser :: SYM r => Parser r
```

the language i am parsing has include directives.

i am using `attoparsec` which is not a monad transformer, so i cannot simply supply a type `Loader = FilePath -> IO (Maybe Text)`.

i can write an interpreter with the following `SYM` instance, that resolves an include.

```
instance SYM r => SYM (Loader -> IO (Either String r)) where
    include path loader = 
        maybe (Left "cannot load") (parseOnly myParser) <$> loader path
```

unfortunately includes in the included file don't get resolved. of course i can resolve them twice to resolve the next layer. but that leads to infinite types if i want to do that for every possible level.

right now i preload all the includes (in a `HashMap`) and bind them, so i can pass a `FilePath -> Maybe Text` to the parser and resolve includes there, but that is clearly not optimal. (and include is not part of `SYM` anymore.)

my question is, how does a finally tagless style deal with that problem?

**edit**: i published a complete example on lpaste: http://lpaste.net/105182

Comment: The `myParser` function doesn't seem right. With the include instance you'd get `Parser (Loader -> IO (Either String r))`, is that what you want? And what is `parseOnly`?

Comment: `parseOnly` is from Attoparsec. and, yes, i think that is the type of the parser. the representation in final encoding is supposed to look like that. i had a newtype in between in my bigger example though. i will make a minimal example.

Comment: I think you've already hit upon the way to solve this: wrap your instance types in a `newtype`, and then you can make them infinitely recursive.  Theoretically `include`s might actually be infinite, so you'll have to deal with that possibility.  Or instead of making your own newtype you can use the free monad to handle each layer of resolution.  Although I usually try to avoid free monads whenever possible (and it's always possible), but YMMV.

Comment: i am not sure i understand what you mean. i will play around it some more and see whether i can get to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was pretty easy in hindsight, but it usually is.

The one-level-only resolving is simply the following.

```
instance SYM r => SYM (Loader -> IO (Either String r)) where
    token t _ = return . Right $ token t
    include path loader =
        maybe (Left "cannot load") (parseOnly myParser) <$> loader path
```

I.e. it will run `parseOnly myParser :: Either String r` on the (successfully) loaded file.

The resolve-everything will just need to select the `SYM (Loader -> IO (Either String r))` instance for the `myParser` and add the `loader` argument:

```
    include path loader =
        maybe (return $ Left "cannot load")
              (either (return ∘ Left) ($ loader) . parseOnly myParser)
              =<< loader path
```

The crucial step is that it will supply the additional parameter loader to the newly `parseOnly`d `SYM` repl, thus selecting the right instance.

A complete snippet is in the annotated lambda paste: http://lpaste.net/105182. test it with entering "include include token"